# What constitutes a suitable counterexample in this proof about cube roots of self adjoint operators?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to show, by counterexample, that the following statement is false:

"Given any self adjoint linear transformation $f, \exists $ a self adjoint linear transformation $g$ such that $f=g^3$"

The proof of the existence of the cube root of $f$, $g$, is easy from using the Spectral Theorem and in matrix form it is the matrix $B = USU^*$, where $U$ is the unitary matrix indicated in the Spectral Theorem and $S$ is the diagonal matrix with the cube roots of the eigenvalues $\lambda_i $ on the diagonal.

The matrix B is clearly not self-adjoint as $B^* = US^*U $ unless all eigenvalues are real.

However, as the cube root is not unique, I feel that there still could exist a self-adjoint cube root and this does not constitute a suitable counterexample. I feel that any counterexample I show does not disprove the statement as there can still exist other cube roots that may be self-adjoint, what would constitute a suitable counterexample for this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Self-adjoint linear mappings indeed have all eigenvalues real. Hence, a self-adjoint cubic root exists. Moreover, the self-adjoint cubic root is uniquely determined.

Comment: Wow, that completely passed me by, I was playing with numbers to find a counterexample for some time, thanks.

Comment: You could take complex cubic roots but then the cubic root operators will only be normal.