# Existence of a self-adjoint endomorphism

Tags: matrices

Let $A$ be an endomorphism on $\mathbb{R}^n.$

I have to prove that there exists a unique self-adjoint endomorphism B such that $B^3 = A$.

Comment: What tools do you have at your disposal - what have you covered already?

Comment: This is (almost) answered [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/976221/what-constitutes-a-suitable-counterexample-in-this-proof-about-cube-roots-of-sel).

Comment: If the endomorphism has a non-real eigenvalue, the claim is false (following  Dietrich's link) .

Comment: This is all with respect to the linear structure?